# Parse result text during SQL query or on Server side

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-function

I have given an example of data table like below. key_value is unique and is used to get search results. What I do currently is query with key_value and then parse the content.

```
+-----+-------------+----------------+
| id  | key_value   | content        |
+-----+-------------+----------------+
| 1   | 001         | 100SW          |
| 2   | 157         | 80SW/20CO      |
| 3   | 222         | 50EA/50CMD     |
| 4   | 275         | 1EA/29LI/70BW  |
+-----+-------------+----------------+
```

What I currently have: (example for key_value: 275)

```
+-----+-------------+----------------+
| id  | key_value   | content        |
+-----+-------------+----------------+
| 4   | 275         | 1EA/29LI/70BW  |
+-----+-------------+----------------+
```

What I want to achieve is something like this. (example for key_value: 275)

```
+-------------+----------+----------+
| key_value   | percent  | content  |
+-------------+----------+----------+
| 275         | 1        | EA       |
| 275         | 29       | LI       |
| 275         | 70       | BW       |
+-------------+----------+----------+
```

Is it possible to achieve on server side with queries?

P.S.: Currently using SQL Server 2005 if it matters.

Comment: for good database design you shouldn't be using the content row that way.
Instead, when the content is added to the DB, you should store it in it's own table,
perhaps with id or keyvalue (from the first table),percent and content. That way you can pull values directly, which will make queries easier in the future since the data is stored in a way that the DB 'understands'.

Comment: it can be done, but function will work slowly. Can you say, if content always will have only 2 letters?

Comment: No @Darka , I can not say that the content will be 2 Letters always. It is generally 2 but there are some 3 or 4 letter contents even if they are rare.

Comment: @serakfalcon That is unfortunately not my structure. That is the way it is given to me . So i'm trying to find my way around it.

Comment: @Mustafa I updated function to get not only content with 2 letters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can create function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].func_split_string
(
    @input as varchar(max)
)
RETURNS @result TABLE
(
    content VARCHAR(20),
    [percent] VARCHAR(20)
)
AS
BEGIN

 DECLARE @name VARCHAR(255)
 DECLARE @content VARCHAR(20)
 DECLARE @percent VARCHAR(20)
 DECLARE @pos INT
 SET @input = @input + '/'
    WHILE CHARINDEX('/', @input) > 0
    BEGIN
      SELECT @pos  = CHARINDEX('/', @input)
      SELECT @name = SUBSTRING(@input, 1, @pos-1)


  SELECT @percent = LEFT (@name, PATINDEX('%[a-zA-Z]%', @name)-1)
  SELECT @content = RIGHT (@name, LEN(@name)-PATINDEX('%[a-zA-Z]%', @name)+1)

      INSERT INTO @result ([percent], content)
      SELECT @percent, @content

      SELECT @input = SUBSTRING(@input, @pos+1, LEN(@input)-@pos)

    END
    RETURN
END
```

and then you can run it like this

```
SELECT t.key_value, fS.[percent], fS.content
FROM yourTableHere as t
CROSS APPLY [dbo].func_split_string(t.[content]) as fS
```

Comment: Seems to be working, Scalar-valued Function is correct or should i choose something else?

Comment: what you mean? This is Table valued function. If answer is correct don't hesitate to mark as answer.

Answer (score 2):

i am not sure if this works for sql server 2005. it does however for sql server 2008. what you do first is a recursive cte, chopping the content at the `/` character (`with...`). you can then split the result in numeric and alphanumeric parts. for your testdata i have used `@t` as you can observe. replace `@t` with the name of your table in the `with... select...`.

```
declare @t table (id int, key_value varchar(3), content varchar(max))

insert into @t
values (1, '001', '100SW')

insert into @t
values (2, '157', '80SW/20CO')

insert into @t
values (3, '222', '50EA/50CMD')

insert into @t
values (4, '275', '1EA/29LI/70BW')

;with data as (
     select key_value
          , case when CHARINDEX('/', content) > 0 
                 then SUBSTRING(content,1,CHARINDEX('/', content)-1)
                 else content
            end as a
          , case when CHARINDEX('/', content) > 0
                 then substring(content,CHARINDEX('/', content)+2, LEN(content)-CHARINDEX('/', content)) 
                 else content
            end as b
       from @t
     union all
     select key_value
          , case when CHARINDEX('/', b) > 0 
                 then SUBSTRING(b,1,CHARINDEX('/', b)-1)
                 else b
            end as a
          , case when CHARINDEX('/', b) > 0
                 then substring(b,CHARINDEX('/', b)+2, LEN(b)-CHARINDEX('/', b)) 
                 else null
            end as b
       from data
      where b is not null
)
select key_value
     , left(a,PATINDEX('%[a-zA-Z]%',a)-1) as [percent]
     , SUBSTRING(a,PATINDEX('%[a-zA-Z]%',a), LEN(a)-PATINDEX('%[a-zA-Z]%',a)+1) as content
  from data
```

Answer (score 1):

please check this ...

```
declare @t table(id int, key_value varchar(50), content varchar(100))

insert into @t values (1 ,'001', '100SW'),(2,'157', '80SW/20CO' ),( 3 ,'222','50EA/50CMD'),(4,'275','1EA/29LI/70BW')

declare @idTofind int = 275

select b.key_value , b.FirstName as name
 from  (select * from 
(
    SELECT distinct  key_value,  S.a.value('(/H/r)[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') FirstName
     , S.a.value('(/H/r)[2]', 'VARCHAR(100)') SecondName, S.a.value('(/H/r)[3]', 'VARCHAR(100)') ThirdName
     FROM 
     (
        SELECT *,CAST (N'<H><r>' + Replace( content, '/','</r><r>') + '</r></H>' AS XML) AS [vals]
        FROM @t
     ) d CROSS APPLY d.[vals].nodes('/H/r') S(a)
) a where key_value = @idTofind
)b
union 
select b.key_value , b.SecondName as name
 from  (select * from 
(
    SELECT distinct  key_value,  S.a.value('(/H/r)[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') FirstName
     , S.a.value('(/H/r)[2]', 'VARCHAR(100)') SecondName, S.a.value('(/H/r)[3]', 'VARCHAR(100)') ThirdName
     FROM 
     (
        SELECT *,CAST (N'<H><r>' + Replace( content, '/','</r><r>') + '</r></H>' AS XML) AS [vals]
        FROM @t
     ) d CROSS APPLY d.[vals].nodes('/H/r') S(a)
) a where key_value = @idTofind
)b
union 
select b.key_value , b.ThirdName as name
 from  (select * from 
(
    SELECT distinct  key_value,  S.a.value('(/H/r)[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') FirstName
     , S.a.value('(/H/r)[2]', 'VARCHAR(100)') SecondName, S.a.value('(/H/r)[3]', 'VARCHAR(100)') ThirdName
     FROM 
     (
        SELECT *,CAST (N'<H><r>' + Replace( content, '/','</r><r>') + '</r></H>' AS XML) AS [vals]
        FROM @t
     ) d CROSS APPLY d.[vals].nodes('/H/r') S(a)
) a where key_value = @idTofind
)b
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the answer from Brett Schneider (that read I after I wrote this query, I should have checked beforehand).

```
WITH Contents AS (
  SELECT key_value
       , value = CASE WHEN CharIndex('/', content) > 0
                      THEN SubString(content, 1, CharIndex('/', content) - 1)
                      ELSE content
                 END
       , next_value 
       = CASE WHEN CharIndex('/', content) > 0
              THEN SubString(content, CharIndex('/', content) + 1
                           , Len(content))
              ELSE ''
         END
  FROM   table1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t1.key_value
       , value 
       = CASE WHEN CharIndex('/', c.next_value) > 0
              THEN SubString(c.next_value, 1, CharIndex('/', c.next_value) - 1)
              ELSE c.next_value
         END
       , next_value 
       = CASE WHEN CharIndex('/', c.next_value) > 0
              THEN SubString(c.next_value, CharIndex('/', c.next_value) + 1
                           , Len(c.next_value))
              ELSE ''
         END
  FROM   table1 t1
         INNER JOIN Contents c ON t1.key_value = c.key_value
  WHERE  c.next_value <> ''
), FindNumber AS (
  SELECT key_value
       , CharPos = CASE WHEN IsNumeric(SubString(value, 3, 1)) = 1 THEN 4
                        WHEN IsNumeric(SubString(value, 2, 1)) = 1 THEN 3
                        ELSE 2
                   END
       , value
  FROM   Contents
)
SELECT Key_Value
     , [Percent] = Cast(SubString(value, 1, CharPos - 1) AS int)
     , Content = SubString(value, CharPos, Len(value))
FROM   FindNumber
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/598b1/20)

The biggest differences are the way we split the number from the string, in my script I check the third then the second character to see if they are number, as the number is a percent there will be never more then 3 number, and that percent is an integer instead of a string.

---

The comment from the OP seems to indicate the search for performance, in that case it's worth noting that sometimes, and I want to really stress the **SOMETIMES** part, translating the `CASE` to some math construct will speed up the execution. The usual trade-off is the readability.
The previous query without the `CASE`s is

```
WITH Contents AS (
  SELECT key_value
       , value 
       = SubString(content, 1
       , Cast(CharIndex('/', content) as bit) * (CharIndex('/', content) - 1)
       + (1 - Cast(CharIndex('/', content) as bit)) * Len(content))
       , next_value 
       = SubString(content
       , Cast(CharIndex('/', content) as bit) * (CharIndex('/', content))
       + (1 - Cast(CharIndex('/', content) as bit)) * Len(content) + 1, Len(content))
  FROM   table1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t1.key_value
       , value 
       = SubString(c.next_value, 1
       , Cast(CharIndex('/', c.next_value) as bit) * (CharIndex('/', c.next_value) - 1)
       + (1 - Cast(CharIndex('/', c.next_value) as bit)) * Len(c.next_value))
       , next_value
       = SubString(c.next_value
       , Cast(CharIndex('/', c.next_value) as bit) * (CharIndex('/', c.next_value))
       + (1 - Cast(CharIndex('/', c.next_value) as bit)) * Len(c.next_value) + 1, Len(c.next_value))
  FROM   table1 t1
         INNER JOIN Contents c ON t1.key_value = c.key_value
  WHERE  c.next_value <> ''
), FindNumber AS (
  SELECT key_value
       , CharPos = 2 
                 + IsNumeric(SubString(value, 3, 1))
                 + IsNumeric(SubString(value, 2, 1))
       , value
  FROM   Contents
)
SELECT *
FROM   FindNumber
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/598b1/37)

How it works:

- `Cast(CharIndex('/', content) as bit)` is 1 if the character '/' is found in content
- `(1 - Cast(CharIndex('/', content) as bit))` is 1 if '/' is not found

that said the formula

```
  Cast(CharIndex('/', content) as bit) * (CharIndex('/', content) - 1)
+ (1 - Cast(CharIndex('/', content) as bit)) * Len(content))
```

in pseudocode is

```
  (IsFound) * (CharIndex('/', content) - 1)
+ (Not IsFound) * Len(content)
```

so if the character is found the formula returns `CharIndex('/', content) - 1`, otherwise it returns `Len(content)`

`IsNumeric` return an int: 1 if the parameter is numeric, 0 if it's not.

Comment: This seems to be working right now. I will try other options too for performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

To separate strings to elements we use [nodes() Method of XML data type](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx). To use it we should convert `content` field to XML format. Just replace `/` with `</x><x>`. And then use [PATINDEX()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx) function to find last digit and first letter (`%[0-9][a-z,A-Z]%` pattern) in the string we divide it to a number and a word.

```
WITH CTE as 
(
select id,key_value,
       CAST('<x>'+REPLACE(content,'/','</x><x>')+'</x>' as XML) as xmlcont
FROM T
), CTE2 as 
(
 SELECT CTE.*,
       a.f.value('data(.)','varchar(1000)') as xmlval
       FROM CTE
  CROSS APPLY CTE.xmlcont.nodes('x') as a(f)
)
  SELECT ID,KEY_VALUE,
         LEFT(XMLval,PATINDEX('%[0-9][a-z,A-Z]%',XMLval)) as [PERCENT],
         SUBSTRING(XMLval,PATINDEX('%[0-9][a-z,A-Z]%',XMLval)+1,1000) as CONTENT
   FROM CTE2
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/db199d/12)</kbd>